# Use filename as name of file when downloading from s3 using boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm uploading a file using boto3 like this:

```
  client = boto3.client('s3', 
           aws_access_key_id = id, 
           aws_secret_access_key = key

  client.upload_file('tmp/test.pdf', 'bucketname', 'test.pdf')
```

Then I generate a download link using `generate_presigned_url`

```
   url = client.generate_presigned_url(
       ClientMethod = 'get_object',
       Params = {
          'Bucket': 'bucketname',
          'key': <randomhash>
      }

   )
```

When I download the file on the link it's named after the key which is a random unique hash - with no extension - I want to give it a specific filename with extension.How can I do that?

Edit: I understand I can use the filename as a key but my issue with this method is that if a users upload the similar filenames the url would link to incorrect/most recent files only. That's why I prefer using a unique hash.

The only drawback with using the unique hash is then my filename for downloading becomes some long hash instead of the filename I gave it when uploading.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this key-value to your `Params`:

```
'ResponseContentDisposition': f"attachment; filename = {filename}"
```

This should set the Content-Disposition header of the download response so that the filename is set.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexa,

You will need to pass the file name in the Key instead of random hash

e.g.

```
url = client.generate_presigned_url(
       ClientMethod = 'get_object',
       Params = {
          'Bucket': 'bucketname',
          'key': 'test.pdf'
      }

   )
```

Comment: I want users to be able to upload files with the same name that's why I'm using the hash but I don't want to use the hash as a filename.

Comment: Your code of uploading files has a constant name called 'test.pdf'. So either you can download the file as object name ie 'test.pdf' or by hash.

Comment: Hey guys I've updated my question - maybe now you can see my issue more clearly. 

Thanks for the help so far guys.