# S3 pre-signed URL : How to maintain original filename when uploading using generate_presigned_url in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to create pre-signed URL for S3 using that we can easily use in any platform(Java, C#, Go) via REST APIs. I've found 2 methods `generate_presigned_url` and `generate_presigned_post`. In case of `generate_presigned_post`, I've heard that using `${filename}` in object key maintains original file name, but in case of `generate_presigned_url`, I'm not seeing a similar option. It literally uses `${filename}` as name of the file when saving to S3. I want to use `generate_presigned_url` as it provides a single link that can be easily used unlike the alternative that required a whole range of form data to upload files. I believe it will complicate the implementation on client end. Anyone know know how to maintain original file name when using `generate_presigned_url` method in Python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use filename as name of file when downloading from s3 using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219164/use-filename-as-name-of-file-when-downloading-from-s3-using-boto3)

Comment: The original file name is in the URL.  What are you using to use the URL to read?  `wget` for example doesn't handle the URL very well.

Comment: @AnonCoward @stdunbar I had checked that one before posting this. To be clear, that question is asking how to download using pre-sgined URL. I am asking how to upload using pre-signed URL.

The thing is, we have to mention the filename when using `generate_presigned_url` and no matter what the original filename the client uses, it will use the filename we provided. I want S3 to keep the original filename

Comment: That's not possible.  S3 has no way to know the original filename, or, for that matter, if there even was a filename.

Comment: @AnonCoward Ok, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381510/aws-s3-presigned-url-file-upload-retain-file-name-in-bucket) I guess in in presigned post, aws does provide an option to get filename from binary instead of requiring it from application that is generating it, but in case of presigned url, I guess that is not possible.

Comment: No, that's allowing the client to specify any filename of its choosing with one URL, it does not require the client to provide the filename of the original object.  The server simply can't know the filename to validate if it's unchanged.